# Unable to build and run c++ code in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

I have setup the correct path for mingw and am successfully able to compile my code using terminal in vscode. But when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to build i get the following error in my terminal

```
Executing task: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g 'c:\Users\Ansh Kapoor\Desktop\cpp\main.cpp' -o 'c:\Users\Ansh 
Kapoor\Desktop\cpp\main.exe'<
/usr/bin/bash: C:MinGWbing++.exe: command not found
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127
```

whereas the same code is successfully executed when I write

```
    g++ main.cpp -o 'main.exe'
```

Now I have checked the path and environment variables and all those things are correct.

Comment: Try `C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe` or `C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe`

Comment: Yes, the missing backslashes in the error message should be the clue

Answer (score 0):

The error in finding the proper path was because of using git bash as the terminal rather than windows powershell or cmd.